# While importing mysqldump file ERROR 1064 (42000) near ' ■/ ' at line 1

Tags: windows, mysql

Cannot import the below dump file created by mysqldump.exe in command line of windows

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `attachment_types` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENTS` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_ATTACHMENT_TYPES___DESCRIPTION` (`DESCRIPTION`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

While importing the file  in command line

```
mysql --user=root --password=root < mysqldumpfile.sql
```

It throws error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) near ' ■/ ' at line 1
```

Somebody please help me.

Comment: did you try to change your CHARSET? maybe use UTF8_general_ci

Comment: @marcosh thank you for pointing me to that. I found the solution. Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Finally I got a solution

We need two options

- `--default-character-set=utf8`: This insures UTF8 is used for each
  field
- `--result-file=file.sql`: This option prevents the dump data
  from passing through the Operating System which likely does not
  use UTF8. Instead it passes the dump data directly to the file
  specified.

Using these new options your dump command would look something like this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 --result-file=database1.backup.sql database1
```

While Importing you can optionally use:

```
mysql --user=root --password=root --default_character_set utf8 < database1.backup.sql
```

Source:http://nathan.rambeck.org/blog/1-preventing-encoding-issues-mysqldump

Comment: Thanks for this Pavan, helped immensely moving dump file from Windows to Linux.

Comment: This exactly solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't forget to define a database (after "utf8" and before "< database1").

Comment: I found that if I don't use --result-file= on Windows 10, my dump file, in addition to failing on import with the error above, ended up being more than double its proper size.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the input file (mysqldumpfile.sql) was created in `UTF-8` encoding so these first 3 bytes "at line 1" invisible to you in the .SQL file is the [byte order mark (BOM) sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

So try to [change default character set to UTF-8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set)

```
mysql --user=root --password=root --default_character_set utf8 < mysqldumpfile.sql
```

Comment: Hi valex , when i entered this command, it says No database selected.

Comment: You have to specify the database at the end of the command. ```mysql --user=root --password=root --default_character_set utf8 <DB_name> < mysqldumpfile.sql```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to import database, this is the import command required on Windows:

```
mysql --user=root --password=root --default_character_set utf8 database2 < database1.backup.sql
```