# mysqpdump command is not working

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I want to take dump of databse. I am using below command but getting error

```
mysqldump -u root -p schemaname >  schemaname_dump.sql
```

Error is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump' at line 1
```

Comment: May help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/13484667/2893413

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the call. Are you sure, your mysqldump matches the version of the server? Otherwise it might try to fetch the data in a manner the server doesn't understand (yet).

Comment: I am accessing the server using putty cli. How can I resolve this problem? or  how can I identify the actual issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752550/while-importing-mysqldump-file-error-1064-42000-near-at-line-1

Comment: @AmiteshKumar it is not helpful in this case :(

Comment: your using windows or Unix ?

Comment: not windows ubuntu server

Comment: Is there any other way to clone DB?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172510/discussion-between-learner-rj-and-amitesh-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mysqldump** is a command you invoke at the shell prompt, not within the mysql client environment.

```
mysql> exit
$ mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql
```

`mysqldump` is not a MySQL command, it is a command line utility. You must call it from your shell command line. I hope you are not calling this from MySQL prompt.

Do not open a `mysql client environment` open command prompt directly type your dump command it will surely work i did it myself.